# Show level surfaces are perpendicular at point $p$.

Tags: solution-verification, vector-analysis, surfaces

> Show that the level surfaces $f(x,y,z)=0$ and $g(x,y,z)=0$ are perpendicular at a point p where $∇f(p)≠ 0$ and $∇g(p)≠ 0$ if and only if $(\frac{∂f}{∂x})(\frac{∂g}{∂x})+(\frac{∂f}{∂y})(\frac{∂g}{∂y})+(\frac{∂f}{∂z})(\frac{∂g}{∂z})=0$ at $p$.

> Show that the surfaces $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$ (with $a$ constant) are perpendicular at every point of intersection.

---

What I have tried

since $∇f(p)≠ 0$ and $∇g(p)≠ 0$ then

$N_g=(\frac{∂g}{∂x},\frac{∂g}{∂y},\frac{∂g}{∂z})$ and $N_f=(\frac{∂f}{∂x},\frac{∂f}{∂y},\frac{∂f}{∂z})$ (both at $p$)

So, for the surfaces to be perpendicular, the normal lines need to be perpendicular, hence,

(at $p$) $0=Ng\cdot Nf=(\frac{∂g}{∂x},\frac{∂g}{∂y},\frac{∂g}{∂z}).(\frac{∂f}{∂x},\frac{∂f}{∂y},\frac{∂f}{∂z})=(\frac{∂f}{∂x})(\frac{∂g}{∂x})+(\frac{∂f}{∂y})(\frac{∂g}{∂y})+(\frac{∂f}{∂z})(\frac{∂g}{∂z})$ as required. This seems like I am on the right lines, however I am a bit uneasy about the point at $p$.

---

Part 2 For the second part I tried to find the normal lines and do the dot product with them both but it did not work out to be zero. For $z^2=x^2+y^2$, I solved for $z$ and used the formula for a graph $(−∂z/∂x,∂z/∂y,1)$ and got $\left(\frac{−x}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}},\frac{−y}{\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}},1\right)$ and $\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{(a^2−x^2−y^2)}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{(a^2−x^2−y^2)}},1\right)$ for $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$. Dot product of these two don't yield zero, this is where I get stuck.

Comment: I see that you have already asked this question [once before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3886916/show-level-surfaces-are-perpendicular-at-a-point-p). You should delete it since I have already answered this one and the previous one has not received any answers till now.

Comment: Deleted, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to part $1$ is correct.

Since the point $p$ lies on both surfaces $z^2=x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$, the dot product$$\begin{align*}&\left(\frac{−x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},\frac{−y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}},1\right)\cdot\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2−x^2−y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{a^2−x^2−y^2}},1\right)\\&=\left(-\frac x{|z|},-\frac y{|z|},1\right)\cdot\left(\frac x{|z|},\frac y{|z|},1\right)\\&=\frac{z^2-x^2-y^2}{z^2}\\&=0.\end{align*}$$Note that you could have also used the previous result by taking the surfaces to be the level curves $f(x,y,z)=z^2-x^2-y^2=0$ and $g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-a^2=0$ and using the result directly.

Comment: Thanks, will try this right now.

Comment: @James Good, and if you are satisfied with my answer, don't forget to accept it by clicking the tick-mark button next to it.

Comment: Done! New to this website so still learning the basics of it, thanks.

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: I am a bit unsure of how we can equate the denominators on the top line all to magnitude of z. Is it simply because at the intersection magnitude of z for both are equal?

Comment: @James The point $P(x,y,z)$ lies on $z^2=x^2+y^2$, so $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=|z|$. Similarly $P$ lies on $x^2+y^2+z^2=a^2$, so $\sqrt{a^2-x^2-y^2}=|z|$.

Comment: Note that we are taking the dot product of gradients at a point of intersection $P(x,y,z)$ of the two surfaces. Only where the two surfaces intersect can we talk about them intersecting orthogonally or not.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks.